# Show traffic like in Maps app from iphone using MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, maps, mkmapview, traffic

I've noticed that the maps app integrated in iOS can show the traffic, but is there a way to do that using MKMapView? or that functionality only appears in that app?.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

The data Apple uses appears to be sourced from [TomTom and others](http://gspe21.ls.apple.com/html/attribution.html). If you can find an API that provides traffic data, you can use a `MKPolyline` to render the data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't show the traffic information using the `MK` framework.

To achieve the results you want I would offer to use the third party resources, *Google Maps API* for example, and use `UIWebView` to present a customized map. [Google Maps JavaScript API v3 TrafficLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#TrafficLayer)

Comment: I've read these exactly words from another post... anyway.. so how are they doing it in the maps app? I mean they are using MKMapView aren't they?, or apple simply didn't release that api?

Comment: why does MKMapView come into the picture when you are using uiwebview? not sure you understand what i am trying to say. just call the Google API and display in uiwebview. its simple.